# The sqlalchemy hybrid_property can not be set during initialization, invalid keyword argument?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, initialization

I have a class of a sqlalchemy model like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Connection(Model):

    name = dbColumn(db.String, nullable=False)
    provider = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    version = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    _connection_status = db.Column('connection_status',db.String, nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def connection_status(self) -> str:
        if not self._connection_status:
            self._connection_status="Connection_Not_Set"
        return self._status

    @connection_status.setter
    def connection_status(self, connection_status: str):
        self._connection_status = connection_status
```

if I try to create a new object:

```
connection=Connection(name="Connection1", status="Initialized")
```

I get an error `'connection_status' is an invalid keyword argument`.

So this appears if I try to set it during initialization. If I set it after the object is created I get no errors, for example:

```
connection=Connection(name="Connection1")
connection.connection_status="Initialized"
```

this works.

Why is the hybrid property not recognized during initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the problem is described here in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25272425/14649310). Essentially because the `hybrid_property` is used in a class (`sqlalchemy` table) level to create SQL queries the getter must have logic that can be directly converted to SQL statements. If someone wishes to have more complex logic like the `if` statement in my example there need to be two different methods one to be used in class level for sql queries with `sqlalchemy` query in it and one to be used in Python level. The method for the class level needs an `.expression` decorator.

In my case above I would have to use a `case` sqlalchemy statement as described in the attached link. For example

```
@connection_status.expression
def connection_status(cls):
    return case((cls._connection_status.is_(None),"Connection_Not_Set"),else_=cls._connection_status)
```

For more information on how to format case statements in sqlalchemy see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case)